# How to use xargs to replace 2 arguments

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I would like to write a script to convert svg files in a directory to png using [svgexport cli](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport)

```
svgexport input.svg input.jpg
```

How can I use find and xargs -I {} to find and print out the svg files using the following:

```
find . -iname -0 "*.svg" | xargs -I {} svgexport {} ???
```

How can I fill-in the second argument by using the first argument and replacing .svg with .jpg?

Comment: Thanks for all the input.

Comment: I presume you are aware that all answers, other than mine, will recurse down into subdirectories, which is not what you asked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's best to do this with a `while` loop:

```
find . -iname "*.svg" -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        svgexport "$file" "${file%.svg}.jpg"
    done
```

Comment: This actually does work just fine with weird filenames, that's the purpose of the `IFS=` and `-d ''` around the `read`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `read -d` to handle null-separated input. Unfortunately, it seems like Debian and Ubuntu built-ins for `read` don't support the `-d` switch. Of course, the `fedora` Docker image I checked didn't have `find` or `xargs`.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Maybe you are not using bash? Bash does support that as does zsh and presumably other shells.

Comment: Understood, though I try to make all my scripts POSIX compliant except when absolutely forced to use bash, so they are more univeral. Alpine linux, for example, doesn't come with `bash` out of the box (though you can install it), and people run things like Alpine linux precisely to get smaller images.

Comment: Try this: `docker run -it --rm debian bash` and do a test on `read -d`. You'll see `sh: 5: read: Illegal option -d`.

Comment: The `-d` option does work for me in the suggested docker image. Specifically it works when I use `bash`, but it does not work when I use `sh`. While `/bin/sh` is a symlink to bash, it seems that it starts bash in a different mode where some newer features (like the `-d` option for `read`) are disabled. BTW different distros have different behavior: in some distros `sh` does in fact behave like `bash`.

Comment: Hmm, strange. It's a hard decision because I really do try to write POSIX-compliant scripts that only require `sh`, not `bash`, in the vast majority of linux flavors, but `read -d` is so helpful compared to `xargs` because then the return value can be handled...

Answer (score 6):

You can use `bash -c` in `xargs` and use BASH's string replacement:

```
find . -name "*.svg" -print0 |
xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'svgexport "$1" "${1%.svg}.jpg"' - {}
```

Comment: Why do you use `-iname` (implying it is case insensitive) when the `${1%.svg}` won't work for upper-case?

Comment: Aha! Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Do them all simply, and faster, in parallel with **GNU Parallel**

```
parallel --dry-run svgexport {} {.}.jpg ::: *.svg
```

Remove the `--dry-run` if you like what it shows you and run it again to actually process the files.

Comment: Thanks. I can't get parallel to work correctly I'm on mac.

Comment: It's simplest with `homebrew`. Then you can just do `brew install parallel`.

Comment: Once you have `homebrew`, your horizons are endless - you can install, update, play with and remove `imagemagick`, `gnuplot`, `redis`, `numpy`, `node`, `tesseract`, `jhead`, `exiftool`, `flac`, `lighttpd`, `nmap`, `tree`, `wireshark`, `gnu-sed` ...

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid `xargs` when you use `find`. It already provides the same feature a simpler way (`-exec` with `+` terminator):

```
find . -iname "*.svg" -exec \
    bash -c 'for i do svgexport "$i" "${i::-3}jpg";done' bash {} +
```

Should you don't want to recurse in subdirectories:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.svg" -exec \
    bash -c 'for i do svgexport "$i" "${i::-3}jpg";done' bash {} +
```

but in that case, `find` is not necessary either:

```
for i in *.[sS][vV][gG]; do svgexport "$i" "${i::-3}jpg"; done
```

If the suffix is always in lowercase, this can be slightly simplified:

```
for i in *.svg; do svgexport "$i" "${i%svg}jpg"; done
```

If your `bash` version doesn't support `${i::-3}`, you can use the portable `{i%???}` instead.

Should you want to avoid the `bash` and `find` GNUisms, here is a POSIX way to achieve the recursive processing:

```
find . -name "*.[Ss][Vv][Gg]" -exec \
    sh -c 'for i do svgexport "$i" "${i%???}jpg";done' sh {} +
```

and another for the non recursive one:

```
for i in *.svg; do svgexport "$i" "${i%???}jpg"; done
```

Comment: I'd use `{i%???}` (or even `${i%.*}`) in any case for the purpose of this answer, then use `sh -c` instead. No need to insert a dependency on `bash` when none is needed.

Comment: @chepner Very true, Answer edited to provide a portable solution. I left the gnuism as it might help to write simpler code when the suffix to remove is much longer, or when its lenght is given as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
find . -iname "*.svg" -print0 | xargs -0 -I \
bash -c 'export file="{}";  svgexport "$file" "${file%.*}.jpg"'
```

Add -print0 to find and -0 to xargs to deal with special filenames.
${file%.*} removes all chars after the last dot, so it will remove ".svg" and you can add the new file extension.

Comment: There's no need to export `file`; it's just a shell variable expanded on the command line, not used internally by `svgexport`.